# levels and nlevels in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and I came upon levels and nlevels function. Can someone explain difference between these two and potential usage ?

Thanks in advance!

I tried both functions and did not understand output of nlevels, but did understand output of levels.

Comment: Just run examples: `levels(iris$Species)` and `nlevels(iris$Species)`. The former gives the levels themselves, the latter how many levels, the count. So in the example, `nlevels` outputs the length of the vector output by the previously run `levels`, which is 3. In plain English, the iris data set records measurements from 3 different species, "setosa", "versicolor" and "virginica".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run examples:

```r
levels(iris$Species)
#> [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"

nlevels(iris$Species)
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The former gives the levels themselves, the latter how many levels, the count.  So in the example, `nlevels` outputs the length of the vector output by the previously run `levels`, which is 3.
In plain English, the `iris` data set records measurements from 3 different species, `"setosa"`, `"versicolor"` and `"virginica"`.